# Perl: proper way to read APNS error_response

Tags: perl, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented a Perl script that sends push notifications through Apples apns services. I am having some issues with the error handling. As per [APNS documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG34)

> If the stream isn't ready for writing, see if the stream is available for reading. If it is, read everything available from the stream. If you get zero bytes back, the connection was closed because of an error such as an invalid command byte or other parsing error. If you get six bytes back, that's an error response that you can check for the response code and the ID of the notification that caused the error. You'll need to send every notification following that one again.

I am doing the same. Whenever I get a write error due to connection drop; I read the socket. Everytime I get 6 bytes return from the socket. Meaning APNS is sending me back an error_response. The format of error-response packet as per [APNS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) is like below

[image]

> The packet has a command value of 8 followed by a one-byte status code and the notification identifier of the malformed notification.

I am using the below code to unpack the data I read from the socket:

```
my $hex = unpack( 'H*', $data );
print $hex;
```

Everytime, I get the same value 080800000000. As per APNS documentation the first byte will always be 8, the next byte will represent the error status code. 8 means "Invalid Token". Up to this part it is OK. However, the remaining 4 bytes which is the identifier, always gives me 00000000. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APNS has two different push notification format, Simple Notification Format and Enhanced Notification Format. The Simple Notification Format does not have a field for specifying the message ID (notification identifier). I was using a Perl module (Net::APNS::Persistent) for communicating with APNS; that only supports Simple Notification Format. Thats why I was always getting 00000000 for the notification identifier part. I updated the code of the module to use the enhanced format which is :

```
pack(
        'cNNnH*na*',                   # format
        1,                             # command
        $id,                           # Notification identifier
        0,                             # expiry timestamp
        32,                            # token length
        $devicetoken,                  # token
        length $json,                  # payload length
        $json                          # payload
    );
```

Then for reading the response I used the below message format:

```
my($c,$status,$identifier) = unpack('ccN',$error);
```

Where $error is the response from APNS. Now the whole thing is working fine.

Comment: I'm the author of Net::APNS::Persistent, and I'm about to start using the module again after some years of not needing it, so I'll change over to the Enhanced notification format asap and push it to CPAN.

Comment: Great to know you decided to update it again. We are using your module and made couple of fixes. We will be happy to share our fixes with you if that helps. Please let me know.